# Can a $C^*$-algebra $A$ be a prime algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

I'm reading Jordan derivation, I'd like to know

**Can a $C^*$-algebra $A$ be a prime algebra?**

**my attempt:**
Let $A$ be  $C^*$-algebra so that  I have to prove, for $a, b\in A$ if $aAb=0$ then either $a=0$ or $b=0$, since $A$ has an approximate identity $(e_\alpha)$ , we get $a e_\alpha b=0$

I'm stuck here give me a hint to show either $a=0$ or $b=0$. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true in general.  Consider $A=C([0,1])$, and define $f,g\in C([0,1])$ by
$$f(t)=\max\left\{\frac12-t,0\right\},\qquad g(t)=\max\left\{t-\frac12,0\right\}.$$ Then $f\cdot C([0,1])\cdot g=0$, but $f\neq0$ and $g\neq 0$.

Comment: Exactly, +1 from me! More generally, in any locally compact Hausdorff space that contains at least $2$ points we can find non-zero $f,g\in C_0(X)$ with $fg=0$ (thus $fC_0(X)g=0$): if $x,y$ are distinct points, find disjoint open neighborhoods $U_x$ and $U_x$ and take compact sets $x\in K_x\subset U_x$ and $y\in K_y\subset U_y$. By Urysohn's lemma we can find $f,g\in C_0(X)$ with $f\vert_{K_x}=1$ and $f=0$ outside $U_x$ and $g\vert_{K_y}=1$ and $g=0$ outside $U_y$. Thus $fg=0$ but $f,g\ne0$.